# get country name from array using country code extracted from forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I am trying to grab the country name from an array called countries that has the countryCode as the keys and the country name as the values. I am extracting the country code from result on ajax call to database. when i get the country code i need to scan through the countries array and pull the value that matches the country code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. No outside libraries to solve just jquery || javascript please.

Here is my attempt to  solve this:

```
function getAllDistributors(){
    $j.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>distributor/index/getAllDistributors',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data.map(JSON.parse));
            results = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(results.distributers);
            var distributors = results.distributers;
            distributors.forEach(function(distributor){
                var countryCode = distributor.country_code;
                console.log(countryCode);
                // returns each country code ex. 'us'
            });

            //var countryName = results['country'];
            //var distributor = results['distributers'];
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the countries array of objects:

```
var countries = [
    {'AT': 'Austria'},
    {'BU': 'Bulgaria'},
    {'CZ': 'Czech Republic'},
    {'DK': 'Denmark'},
    {'EE': 'Estonia'},
    {'FI': 'Finland'},
    {'FR': 'France'},
    {'DE': 'Germany'},
    {'HU': 'Hungary'},
    {'IE': 'Ireland'},
    {'IT': 'Italy'},
    {'NL': 'Netherlands'},
    {'NO': 'Norway'},
    {'PL': 'Poland'},
    {'PT': 'Portugal'},
    {'RM': 'Romania'},
    {'SI': 'Slovenia'},
    {'ES': 'Spain'},
    {'SE': 'Sweden'},
    {'CH': 'Switzerland'},
    {'TR': 'Turkey'},
    {'GB': 'United Kingdom'},
    {'CA': 'Canada'},
    {'MX': 'Mexico'},
    {'PR': 'Puerto Rico'},
    {'US': 'USA'},
    {'AR': 'Argentina'},
    {'BR': 'Brazil'},
    {'AU': 'Australia'},
    {'IN': 'India'},
    {'MY': 'Malaysia'},
    {'NZ': 'New Zealand'},
    {'CN': 'People\'s Republic of China'},
    {'SG': 'Singapore'},
    {'SK': 'South Korea'},
    {'TW': 'Taiwan'},
    {'UA': 'United Arab Emirates'}
];
```

Comment: Can you change the `countries` array, as it's a horrible construct? Make it an object with keys instead, and all you have to do is `countries[countryCode]`

Comment: Yes, I can. How would you construct it?

Comment: Nm, you already mentioned how. Thank you

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @adeneo add your first reply as a answer so i can add your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter and check the property

`countries.filter(a=> a.hasOwnProperty(countryCode.toUpperCase()) ? a : null )`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer i ended up going with thank to @adeneo. I appreciate everyone else's help as well.

```
function getAllDistributors(){
    $j.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>distributor/index/getAllDistributors',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data.map(JSON.parse));
            results = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(results.distributers);
            var distributors = results.distributers;
            distributors.forEach(function(distributor){
                var cc = distributor.country_code.toUpperCase();
                countryCode = cc.replace("\\s+","");
                console.log(countries[countryCode]);
            });

            //var countryName = results['country'];
            //var distributor = results['distributers'];
        }
    });
}
```

As for the countries array i made it an object with keys instead.

```
var countries = {'AU': 'Australia', 'US': 'United States'};
```